# Apache config SetEnv variable only if not set

Tags: apache-2.4, conditional, setenv

I have a fairly high traffic web server and would like to squeeze some micro optimization out of it.

In Apache's config I have:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI "\.a?png$" dontlog
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI "\.bmp$" dontlog
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI "\.css$" dontlog
...several more
```

I'd like to achieve this (pseudo-code):

```
<If env=!dontlog>
    SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI "\.a?png$" dontlog
</If>
<If env=!dontlog>
    SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI "\.bmp$" dontlog
</If>
<If env=!dontlog>
    SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI "\.css$" dontlog
</If>
...several more
```

Performing a config test using my pseudo-code results in:

> AH00526: Syntax error on line 260 of C:/apache24/conf/httpd.conf:
> Cannot parse condition clause: syntax error, unexpected T_OP_STR_EQ, expecting '('

---

Note:

Please ignore the regex triviality of the examples. How can I perform short-circuiting?

Answer (score 0):

[`SetEnvIfNoCase`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_setenvif.html#setenvifnocase) performs regular expression matching  in a case-insensitive manner.

So rather than finding a complex work-around to avoid processing separate `SetEnvIfNoCase` tests  and multiple trivial regular expressions, reduce your test to a single, slightly more complex, regular expression that matches all file extensions you don't want to log.

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI "\.(?:jpe?g|css|bmp|a?png)$" dontlog
```

---

Also consider storing and serving your images in a separate subdomain. If you believe logging an unnecessary performance penalty, that allows you to configure a VirtualHost without any logging, which then completely avoids the need for separate testing if a request should or shouldn't be logged.

People claim that an images / static content subdomain will improve pagespeed because a browser can open additional connections to the subdomain, you don't have to set/process cookies there etc. etc. And even if you don't want to use a CDN for your main site, you can still  easily use one for your static content.

Comment: Thank you, I am aware that I can combine those simple regexes into a larger one but it doesn't lend itself well to readability especially if encountered by someone who is not me in the future. I have several much more complicated regexes which perform ip-based restrictions which would benefit from short-circuiting; CIDR notation is not feasible for our networking madness. We have 3 million page hits a month and on average 30-50 assets being loaded.

Comment: People can't answer questions you don't ask and for which you don't provide the right context or incomplete information. ***To me*** your question is only about how to make *your **attempted** solution* work, where IMHO your attempted solution is the completely  wrong approach to reduce the number `SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI` directives that need to be processed. - If you have a different question, ask that, with full context rather then how to make your (possibly wrong) attempted approach work.

Comment: I disagree. I asked `I'd like to achieve this (pseudo-code):` **not** "help me combine this regex". Your desire to take the path of least resistance was your choice.